# Ruby on Rails not recognizing route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails, from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html , But when I try to set the root for the route up in Section 4.3, although the route is recognized, when I run the server and localhost:3000, it still thinks there's no root route. What could the problem be? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Please add your config/routes.rb file to your question.

Comment: Should be `root 'controller#action'`  Older versions of rails is  `root to: 'controller#action'`

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

Without your `routes` file, or even the error which is being presented, I'll just give you what you need to get the "root" route working:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index" #-> syntax - "controller#action"
```

This has to be backed up with the appropriate controller action:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end
```

It also needs the appropriate views:

```
#app/views/application/index.html.erb
This is the root page!
```

Comment: `root: "application#index"` gives a syntax error (that's an hash hanging around without even braces). As commented by CWitty, it's `root 'application#index'` or `root to: 'application#index'`.